# WordPress Custom Post Featured Image, Title and Content Social Media Sharing

Tags: php, wordpress, sharing

I want to share custom post featured image, title and small content of post text. How can I do that? I tried to do it with sharethis WordPress plugin but it shares logo of my site and useless content. This is my code please help me.

This is my code of single post:

```
  <div class="row">
 <!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside class="col-sm-4 sidebar sidebar-right">
        <?php require_once('template/advertisment/postview_side_advertisment.php'); ?>
        <?php require_once('template/postview/side_recentpost.php'); ?>
    </aside>
    <!-- /Sidebar -->
    <!-- Article main content -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 maincontent">
        <?php
        setPostViews(get_the_ID());
        ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1 class="inner-page-header"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <h4>
                <?php echo get_the_date("F j, Y g:i a", $post_id); ?>
            </h4>
            <h5><?php
                echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
                ?></h5>
            <div class="social-sh col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <span class='st_facebook_large' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>'
                          st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span>
                    <span class='st_googleplus_large' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>'
                          st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span>
                    <span st_via='@saruwathlk' st_username='saruwathlk' class='st_twitter_large'
                          st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span>
                    <span class='st_linkedin_large' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>'
                          st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span>
                    <span class='st_blogger_large' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>'
                          st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span>
                    <span class='st_flipboard_large' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>'
                          st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></span>
            </div>
            <hr style="margin-top:9px; margin-bottom:0px">
            <?php echo the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </article>
    <?php echo the_title(); ?>
    <?php echo the_permalink(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, you will need to setup open graph meta tags in your site `head`. Here is an article with a pretty good breakdown on how to accomplish that: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-open-graph-tags-to-wordpress.